# Vault .NET - Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine

Tags: azure-keyvault, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault, consul-kv, vault

I've added all my configuration details in the Vault. The detail you can see in the attached image below. This follows a specific path i.e **kv/unistad/dev/workflow/camunda/1.0**

[image]

However, when I try to read this information using [Vault.NET](https://github.com/Chatham/Vault.NET) with the following nuget package

```
Install-Package Vault
```

My code looks something like this:

```
var endpoint = "http://openblue-bridge.com:32270";
var token = "s.inklpUdNxet1ZJtaCLMpEIPA";

var vaultClient = new VaultClient(new Uri(endpoint), token);

string project = "unistad";
string environment = "dev";
string appVersion = "1.0";
var secretPath = $"kv/{project}/{environment}/workflow/camunda/{appVersion}";
// Use client to read a key-value secret.
var secrets = await vaultClient.Secret.Read< Dictionary<string, string>> (secretPath);
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

> Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for
> the appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use
> 'vault kv get' for this operation.

I'm not sure how can I fix this error. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using v2 of the kv engine. For that engine, you need to have `/data/` in the path, as shown in the [API docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v2). The requirement for this prefix is also described in [the engine docs](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2#acl-rules).

So the solution to your problem is specifically to change your path from

```
var secretPath = $"kv/{project}/{environment}/workflow/camunda/{appVersion}";
```

to

```
var secretPath = $"kv/data/{project}/{environment}/workflow/camunda/{appVersion}";
```